# Does HttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream() retry on connect timeout?

Tags: java, http, tcp, httpurlconnection

I was having a problem where [HttpURLConnection](http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).[getOutputStream](http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getOutputStream())() took 2-3 seconds. I set the connect timeout using HttpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout, expecting a SocketTimeoutException (wrapped by IOException) to be thrown from getOutputStream(), so I could retry the whole operation on another server.

Instead, it just works now. Does getOutputStream() try to connect internally if it gets a SocketTimeoutException?

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this [addressed here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout(int))?

Comment: "Some non-standard implmentation of this method may ignore the specified timeout. To see the connect timeout set, please call getConnectTimeout()."

Answer (score 1):

If you setConnectTimeout(), it will not retry. Otherwise, it tries just one more time before it throws IOException.

In my opinion, you should handle retry yourself though.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: No. We found out this behavior while looking at some HTTP traces and confirmed by looking at Java 5 source code. So this is only a special behavior of Java 5's URL handler.

Comment: The thing is ... I found that setting the timeout did seem to cause internal retries. I'm downloading the code now.